# c# getting right encoding for data in postgresql database

Tags: c#, postgresql, character-encoding

I have Postgresql database with UTF8 encoding and collation set to Windows1250.

It is used by application written in Delphi and accessed using ODBC driver which has optional parameter:
*set client_encoding=LATIN2.*

In that application all strings from database are displayed correctly.
Now I want to get database data using c# application but I could not get right encoding.

I have tried using different client_encodings and Encoding class to get it right but without success.

For example character 'š' is one of characters that don't display well.

- with default encoding (utf8) I am getting \u009a
- with *set client_encoding = latin2* I am getting ? char
- with *set client_encoding = windows1250* I am getting error: "character with byte sequence 0xc2 0x9a in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding WIN1250".

Any suggestions how to solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

**SOLUTION:** 
I finally get a right string by using:

```
Encoding.Default.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding("Latin2").GetBytes(stringFromDB));
```

Comment: Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Code block should look like `code block`. Use **bold** *italics* if needed. This is highly unreadable.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: `client_encoding` has to be set to the encoding that you C# application expects the strings to have.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I am not sure I got the point. How do I know which encoding c# application expects? I just want to have same display result as application written in Delphi has.

Comment: @Prateek Sorry for bad formatting. It was my first post here... But I have make my post look a little bit better now :)

Comment: So why are you not just using utf8 everywhere?

Comment: @Nyerguds I could not use utf8 everywhere because delphi 5, as far as I know,  don't have support for utf8 encoding. But I found solution and add it in post above.

Comment: @yiwan Don't edit your solution into the question. [Post it as actual answer and accept that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), so the StackOverflow system can see that this question has a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get a right string by using:

```
Encoding.Default.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding("Latin2").GetBytes(stringFromDB));
```